# Is it right or wrong to register 32bit local server in 64bit registry part?

Tags: windows, com, ms-office, wow64

A COM object implemented as 32bit local server (.exe) registering itself on 64bit windows gets redirected by WOW64 by default (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253.aspx). When a client requests an instance, the system will normally search in both parts, unless explicit context flags are set (CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_##_BIT_SERVER).

Therefore it is possible to use 32bit COM addins (implemented as local server) with MS Office 2010 64bit. It only requires to write the MSO specific registry keys into the 64bit part too (KEY_WOW64_64KEY).

Since MS Office 2013 64bit only COM objects registered in the 64bit registry part are loaded, possibly because it explicitly requests 64bit servers only. There seems to be no reason for this restriction. Was this change between 2010 and 2013 made accidentally or intentionally?

Registering the 32bit local server into the 64bit part solves the problem, but does it conform to the rules? May a 32bit local server be registered in the 64bit part or must it be in the redirected 32bit part? Would it disregard the client's intent or is it a way to signal compatibilty with 64bit clients?

As far as I understand, MSO 2013 does not want to support 32bit addins although technically possibly.

EDIT (to be more precise): I'm not asking if it works (I know that it does). I'm not interested in tricks to make things work that are not intended to. It just lead me to the question which COM objects (local server, aka out-of-process server) should be registered in 64bit part: Those implemented in 64bit or those that can be used by 64bit clients (even if they are implemented in 32bit)?

EDIT (to be more general): Although my question refers to MSO as client intantiating a COM object, it can be asked more generally. Think of an Application providing automation, implemented as 32bit EXE. By default it's self registration gets redirected to Wow6432Node, but that's no problem. When a client requests an instance, it will be found by the system anyway (unless the client restricts to 64bit servers only). Therefore it's usually not necessary to register to the 64bit part too, but is it wrong (for 32bit EXE)? What does it mean, what are the consequences? Are there any rules, recommendations, ...?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly OK to register a 64-bit proxy DLL in the 64-bit registry.

Just don't register a 32-bit proxy DLL in the 64-bit registry.

Comment: I'm not talking about DLLs (inprocserver) but EXEs (localserver). As DLLs are loaded into the calling's process address space it's obvious that bitness must match. Whereas it's obvious on the other hand that bitness doesn't matter in inter process scenarios (btw: in former versions of WOW64 the key HKLM\...\CLASSID was not only redirected but reflected when not specifying inproc server or handler. Which means there was no difference in case of local servers.) Registering 32bit EXEs in 64bit part does work, but does it conform to the rules?

Comment: EXEs have to have proxy DLLs to handle marshaling.  So the only thing that matters is the bitness of the proxy DLL.

Comment: I'm not an expert in COM, but as far as I know (and experienced) proxy DLLs are not mandatory. My COM object is hosted in a 32bit EXE which is registered by means of LocalServer32 key, no stubs, proxies, etc. And it works with 64bit client (MSO 2010 by default, MSO 2013 only when explicitly registered in 64bit part too). I guess marshalling is handled by the system.

Comment: @marx That might be true if all your interfaces are automation-compatible.  In my experience, I've always needed a proxy DLL.